# How can I display crosshair labels on top of the chart with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

How can I render crosshair labels to the top of a HighStock chart?

Right now the crosshair label is rendered on to the xAxis which is and should be located at the bottom of the chart.

Is there a way to change the label's position to top of the chart without changing the position of the xAxis? In the end crosshair and label should look like a flag and not like a reversed flag.

```
const chart = Highcharts.StockChart({
chart: {
    renderTo: "chart",
},

credits: { enabled: false },
navigator: { enabled: false },
scrollbar: { enabled: false },
tooltip: { enabled: false },
rangeSelector: { inputEnabled: false },

series: [{
    type: "area",
    data: dataSet
  }
],

xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    crosshair: {
        color: lineColor,
        label: { enabled: true, align: "right" }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crosshair label is coupled with a specific axis. However, you can create two linked x axes. Top axis should be invisible but should be coupled with the crosshair and the label.

```
xAxis: [{
  opposite: true,
  crosshair: {
    label: {
      enabled: true,
      align: "right"
    }
  },
  visible: false
}, {
  linkedTo: 0,
  gridLineWidth: 1
}],
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/p8fqq35v/